# How to copy the Whole data from Data Grid view to excel in powershell script

Tags: powershell, user-interface, gridview

I am trying to make a script to create a billing GUI for a small startup.
To list out the products based on the user input I have created a Datagridview. I have managed to list the products in the grid, but am struck now when trying to copy the same to excel

Comment: What do you mean "...copy the same to excel"? Do you want to copy the data to an existing Excel workbook? If you want a fresh export, you can try `$data | Export-Csv "C:\path\to\file.csv" -NoTypeInformation`

Comment: @Karthick ganesan,
i want to copy the content(user input) from the datagridview to the excel sheet in the specific column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download PSExcel module from https://github.com/RamblingCookieMonster/PSExcel Import it using Import-Module.

Then use the following code:

```
$File = "Path to xlxs file"
$WSName = "SheetName"
$ColumnName = "E" 
$StartRowIndex = 2
$ColumnData = @("a","b","c","d")
$i = 0
$Excel = New-Excel -Path $File
$Worksheet = $Excel | Get-WorkSheet -Name $WSName
ForEach ($data in $ColumnData) {
($Worksheet.Cells | ? {$_.Address -eq "$ColumnName$($StartRowIndex +$i)"}).Value = $data
$i++
}
$Excel | Close-Excel -Save
```

**$File** is a full path to your excel document
**$WSName** is a worksheet name in excel document you're opening
**$ColumnName** is a column address (as in excel)
**$StartRowIndex** is a starting row index you want yout data to be inserted   (start from 1 as in excel)
**$ColumnData** is an array of values you want to put in your excel worksheet
If you need to export ENTIRE  datagridview table (or part of it), use :

```
$File = "Path to xlxs file"
$WSName = "SheetName"
$data | Export-XLSX -Path $File -Worksheet $WSName
```

Where **$data** is a PSObject (same as for Export-Csv).
Use -ClearSheet switch if worksheet already exists in Excel document and you need to paste your data over the existing one.